# Getting an error after updating .NET 6 Azure function to .NET 8 and FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to "dotnet-isolated"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

Some time getting this exception in azure app insights logs and couple of function request is failing to response. Mostly it's happening on the 1st request only if we hit the function after certain period of time. I thought that could be for not to set keep alive for this function but keep alive has set for this function.

Here are error logs:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.GerData Result: Failure
>
> Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore.DefaultHttpCoordinator.SetFunctionContextAsync(String invocationId, FunctionContext context)

Function code :

```
[Function("Getdata")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req)
{
    try
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Getdata function started.");
       
        var response = new OkObjectResult("success");

        req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "Deny");
        req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
        req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        
        req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
        req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000");
        return response;               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogError($"Getdata: Fetch failed. Exception: {ex.Message}, Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException}");
        req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "Deny");
        return new BadRequestObjectResult("Fetch failed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: I have updated the code block. This is a very simple function migrated from .net 6 to 8 . Thank you for your response. Not getting the the issue locally or not frequently. Only happening when function has idea for a certain period of time .

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the function taking too long to respond to the requests. To resolve this, try setting the function timeout property in the  `host.json`  file:

```json
{
  "functionTimeout": "00:30:00"
}
```

- Monitor the resource consumption of your Azure Function during execution, such as CPU and memory usage.
- It could also happen if the function is getting terminated by the host due to resource constraints. Scale up your function app.

---

I have tested the same in my environment with .NET 6 Azure Function, able to run the function successfully in both local and Azure Function app in portal as well(after certain period of time as you mentioned above).

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Getdata function started.");

            var response = new OkObjectResult("success");

            req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("X-Frame-Options", "Deny");
            req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
            req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

            req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
            req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000");
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Getdata: Fetch failed. Exception: {ex.Message}, Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException}");
            req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("X-Frame-Options", "Deny");
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("Fetch failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

**.csproj:**

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Tested the function multiple times after certain time, able to run the function without any issues:

- **Application Insights:**

[image]

- **Portal Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response @Pravallika KV. I was also downgrade to .net 6 and today when I checked the log then also see there are exception are there in the log . This issue is not for every request as well as time out issue . this is very simple function which does not have any business logic. Getting success on in few millisecond.

Comment: Did you try with functionTimeout attribute?

Comment: Yes I have set it to 10 min  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",

Comment: Here is today's exception logs : Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral,

Comment: Check this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/598791/azure-function-fails-with-functioninvocationexcept).

Comment: Thanks for the Ans link. In my scenario, azure function is in premium plan.  Function hit is also very less because it's in nonprod and only few peoples are using this function only. I am also totally clue less why it's happening.

Comment: Did you try implementing the properties `maxOutstandingRequests` and `maxConcurrentRequests`?

Comment: Function app under Dedicated plan and default set to -1